# SFTP Chroot for Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, ssh, sftp

I'm attempting to setup SFTP (OpenSSH 6.1 internal-sftp) so that a group of users(sftpusers) can access my server specifically to work on development of my website:

```
 Match Group sftpusers
        Chrootdirectory /srv/sftp/shared
        AllowTCPForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I have created the chroot (/srv/sftp/shared) owned by root. Apache virtual directories are pointing to folders in /srv/sftp/shared/www. This folder is owned by www-data as expected:

```
drwxrwxr-x 5 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 13 20:39 /srv/sftp/shared/www
drwxr-x--- 3 root sftpusers 4096 Oct 13 19:41 /srv/sftp/shared
```

Apache error is:

```
[Sun Oct 13 22:04:15 2013] [crit] [client 117.62.133.161] (13)Permission denied: /srv/sftp/shared/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable Verified virtual directories are set to shared/www, not shared
```

I am able to access all of these files via SFTP. My problem is that when attempting to access my sites from a web browser now I'm getting "Permission Denied" errors which I assume comes from having these folders in the chroot. How can I allow Apache access to this chroot?

Comment: Can you list the permissions on the folder and parent? (`ls -al /srv/sftp/shared; ls -al /src/sftp/shared/www`). Any errors in Apache logs?

Comment: drwxrwxr-x 5 www-data www-data  4096 Oct 13 20:39 /srv/sftp/shared/www
drwxr-x--- 3 root sftpusers 4096 Oct 13 19:41 /srv/sftp/shared
Apache error is:
[Sun Oct 13 22:04:15 2013] [crit] [client 117.62.133.161] (13)Permission denied: /srv/sftp/shared/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
Verified virtual directories are set to shared/www, not shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied, particularly the bold statement that says **search the directory containing those files, along with all parent directories up to the root of the filesystem**. Apache needs to be able to read / execute on the parent directories of the `DocumentRoot`. Try making sure that `others` have `+rx` permissions on all the folders:

```
chmod -R o+rX /srv
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks! My concern with playing with the permissions of the directories was that I was afraid it would break the chroot but this did NOT. I am still able to SFTP and now my sites are up. Thanks again!